# Rotating a SVG path using CSS3 around its own center

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have a set of SVG path, one of them is as follows:

```
<path id="GOL" class="st0" d="M37.5,430.5l-12.4-12.4v-13.3h-4.2c-7.2,0-13.9,2.5-18.7,7.5c-4.7,4.9-7.3,11.3-7.3,18.3
    c0,7,2.6,13.5,7.3,18.3c4.8,5,11.4,7.6,18.6,7.6l4.2,0v-13.7L36.7,430.5z M19.7,435.3l-4.9-4.9l4.9-4.9l4.9,4.9L19.7,435.3z
     M2.4,430.5c0-8.4,5.6-15.1,13.1-16.9v3.8L2.4,430.5l13.1,13.1v3.8C8,445.6,2.4,438.9,2.4,00.5z"></path>
```

I try to make a rotate-animation with the below code:

```
.stuck #GOL
{
  fill: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#GOL
{
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

The problem is that the path rotates around a distance center which is not regular. I want it to rotate around its own center. I have to use CSS3 (so I can't use svg's own `rotate()` function).

Comment: You'll probably need JS to determine the center of the path shape.

Comment: no way to determine it using CSS?

Comment: No..CSS can't "detect" anything. You could try `transform-origin: 50% 50%` but that's not necessarily supported cross-browser as i recall and may not be what you are actually after. A demo might be of some use here.

Comment: What does `.stuck` do in this context? What kind of element is it?

Comment: To be more specific, you can specify the center of rotation via CSS (using `transform-origin`). What CSS can't do for you is find the "center" by itself, you'll have to find those values by some other means.

Comment: NB: providing a working jsFiddle or snippet would probably be helpful, along with what you consider should be the "center"

Comment: I searched the whole net. It's not possible, unless through using some sort of javascript...which I'm not after for some reasons. .stuck is a class of the parent container in a certain event. It's just related to the parent container not the svg itself.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `transform-origin` in your CSS?

```
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

This will start any transform from the middle of the selector.

Comment: Actually, the default value of `transform-origin` already is `50% 50% 0`, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Comment: But the meaning of `50% 50%` differs between browsers. Because the spec changed Chrome now does the "wrong" thing. For now, it is safer to use absolute coordinates. Ie. `transfer-origin: 100px 100px`.

Comment: Confirmed NOT repeat NOT working in chrome 64 and Firefox 58. This is working for DOM elements, but NOT for SVG elements. This has been working in older version also for SVG elements.

Comment: @MartinMeeser any way to make this rotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the use of `transform-origin` and its associated browser issues by using nested transforms.

The basic idea is to transform the centre of rotation for the path to the origin (top left) of the SVG do the rotation and transform it back to its original position.  You can achieve this with nested groups.

The centre of your crown shape is at approx (22, 432). So we can do:

```
<g transform="translate(22 432)">   // translate everything to the path's original position
  <g transform="rotate(90deg)">     // rotate (around the origin)
    <path transform="translate(-22 -432)"/>  // shift path to the origin
  </g>
</g>
```

Read the transforms from the inside (the path) to the outermost group.

Demo below:

```css
#GOL
{
  fill: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#GOL
{
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">

  <g transform="translate(22 432)">
    <g id="GOL">
      <path class="st0" d="M37.5,430.5l-12.4-12.4v-13.3h-4.2c-7.2,0-13.9,2.5-18.7,7.5c-4.7,4.9-7.3,11.3-7.3,18.3
    c0,7,2.6,13.5,7.3,18.3c4.8,5,11.4,7.6,18.6,7.6l4.2,0v-13.7L36.7,430.5z M19.7,435.3l-4.9-4.9l4.9-4.9l4.9,4.9L19.7,435.3z
     M2.4,430.5c0-8.4,5.6-15.1,13.1-16.9v3.8L2.4,430.5l13.1,13.1v3.8C8,445.6,2.4,438.9,2.4,00.5z"
        transform="translate(-22 -432)"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```